# How to get default value and condition value of firebase config via REST API?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I tried to get default value and condition value but when I set it to String value it did not show the value I want. Please see the code below

```
    Template template = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance(testAPP).getTemplateAsync().get();
    ParameterValue parameterValue = template.getParameters().get("test_config").getDefaultValue();
    ParameterValue parameterValue2 = template.getParameters().get("test_config2").getConditionalValues().get("New APP");

    System.out.println(parameterValue.toString());
    System.out.println(parameterValue);
```

It shows the value like this

> com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.ParameterValue$Explicit@c21a1458
> com.google.firebase.remoteconfig.ParameterValue$Explicit@c21a1458

The value I want to it will showing the String like this

```
test config 1
```

And this is the remote config in firebase
[image]

Anyone know the way to get it?

Answer (score 2):

Now, it ok with

```
 String value = ((ParameterValue.Explicit) parameterValue).getValue();
```